# How to efficiently match hundred thousands of substring in one string using elasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

My problem is simple: I have a database containing 400,000 substrings (movies and tv shows titles).
I'd like to match these titles in a message such as:

> I really love **Game Of Thrones** and **Suits**, also **Spotlight** is an awesome
>   movie.

What I need is to match **Game Of Thrones**, **Suits** and **Spotlight** in this string.

I tried to send all titles to wit.ai but it seems that it can't handle 100,000 substrings.

I'm wondering if elasticsearch could do the job?

If that's a common problem, sorry, could you help me to search in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One of the best algorithms to find strings from dictionary in a text is [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) one

> dictionary-matching algorithm that locates elements of a finite set of
>   strings (the "dictionary") within an input text. It matches all
>   strings simultaneously. The complexity of the algorithm is linear in
>   the length of the strings plus the length of the searched text plus
>   the number of output matches.

But I wonder that your database engine does not provide possibilities for such searching... Probably it really can, but you don't know?

Comment: Thanks, that could help.
I also wonder I'm trying to search for such functionalities with PostgreSQL, or elastic search.